# Can I set a tablet to wake up when moved or when I touch the screen?

Tags: standby

I intend to buy a an Android tablet for a single use, as a remote control. It'll run a single app all the time and sit in a dock most of the time, occasionally being carried to another room. I want two features: stay awake while charging (searching this site showed me a few app solutions for this), and for the tablet to wake up when moved or when the screen is touched. Basically, I want as little time and as few manipulations as possible to get from just lying there on a coffee table to being awake and responsive. I expect this will decrease battery life (because the touch detection or accelerometers have to be active), and given my use case, that's ok as long as I still get 3-4 hours out of it.

I don't have a specific tablet picked out yet, but I'm thinking something along the lines of the Galaxy Tab 8.9". The 7" screen size would be fine, but I want to us this in landscape mode all of the time and that works better if the dock connector is on the bottom while in landscape mode.

Comment: Most tablets wake up by pushing a single button, why do you want it easier?

Comment: That single button is often small and hard to find. Even if it is like the home button on a iDevice, it is much easier to tap or brush the screen. It's even easier than that if the screen wakes up when I pick up the tablet. How many motions do you need to make to wake up your average TV remote control?

Comment: "*easier to tap or brush the screen*" is not a good idea because that means - the app to do that, would be polling in the background monitoring for touches, which in turn has dire negative consequence of draining the battery... just saying :)

Comment: Yea, I understand that I've got to have the touch hardware active, the use case is this thing sits in a charging cradle 99% of the time and occasionally gets carried around to different rooms, then put back in the cradle at night. I really only need 3-4 hours of use between charges. Or if I can get the motion unlock stuff working maybe monitoring the accelerometers take less juice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more, I found [Wake Up Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wildroid.wake.up.screen). It might do what I want. I'll try it out in a few days.

Comment: "Wake Up Screen" does what I want.

Answer (score 5):

There is a free app called MotionUnlock, with it your tablet will sense when it is being picked up from a table, etc... and unlock automatically, being ready for use!

[MotionUnlock - Tablet Wake Up](http://www.apkbrain.com/apps/MotionUnlock---Tablet-Wake-Up-121464.html)

Comment: Any idea why it's not in the Play store but in that suspicious-looking webstore?

Comment: Not a clue as to why it isn't published, but it appears on several other websites.

Comment: A quick google search didn't turn up other sites. Also, going to the publisher's site and looking under "apps" doesn't show that software.

Comment: The software isn't mine, so can't really tell as to why it is not present on the market, but I use it and works well. Related to other sites [Podnova](http://android.podnova.com/software/924215.htm) and [AndroidPIT](http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.phonephreak.motionunlock/MotionUnlock-Tablet-Lift2Wake) can serve as an example!

Comment: It appears that the app is no longer available, so this isn't actually an answer to my question.

Comment: @StevenRoose apkbrain is the alternative to google play if you do not sign in to all kinds of things associated with google. Have not used it but would be extremely careful with it :) That's not to say its junked with malware, ripoffs, pirated versions etc, its, *the* alternative to Google Play.

Comment: I only knew about AndroidLib, but I know there are plenty more. ApkBrain is not in this top5 list: http://www.howtogeek.com/106175/the-top-5-alternatives-to-the-android-market/ Don't confuse it with AppBrain, which is known to me :)

Comment: The MotionUnlock developer direct contact: "Stefan Giesewetter" <sgiesew@gmx.de>.